# Drawing dynamic text on video stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to change text dynamically every 5 minutes on my live video stream
This is the argument im using:

```
-vf "drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"
```

I tried 'c' in the FFMPEG console windows but I can't get it right, I always get a parse error.
Is there an example of how to use this options?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use `textfile='/path/to/file':reload=1` in place of `text=''`

Comment: @Mulvya How does is read from the file? And how often will it reload?

Answer (score 2):

Exept a reload you also need to write the file atomically. Update the text to a temporarily file first and then rename it. If not, at some point FFMpeg will read null data and fails when the file is created and no text is written yet.

- Create livetext.txt.tmp with the text for the next 5 minutes.
- Rename livetext.txt.tmp to livetext.txt.

repeat this process every 5 minutes.

```
-vf "drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:textfile=/path/livetext.txt:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:reload=1"
```

With reload Ffmpeg reads the text every frame, so updates are almost instantaneous. For details see [Drawtext filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-drawtext-1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to draw text with stream copy?

Comment: This is a big NO. If you use filters you can't use streamcopy.

Comment: I have tried to create livetext.txt.tmp with updated text every 1 second and rename it to livetext.txt file. However, I still encountered livetext.txt file could not be read in ffmpeg.