# Reload scrolling drawtext filter in ffmpeg only while off screen

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have a drawtext filter in ffmpeg that scrolls right to left on the bottom of the screen showing current weather data. The problem I have is the text file containing the weather data updates every 2 seconds and when the weather readings change the length of the text also changes. This causes the looping text to jump around. I tried using a conditional statement to set reload to 1 only if x was greater than the screen width but it seems reload doesn't evaluate conditional statements. Can anyone think of a way around this problem so that the text will only update once per loop, while off screen?

My command:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://192.168.x.x:7447" -i /YouTubeStream/CupolaCam/logo.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=20:925","drawbox=x=0:y=ih-35:w=iw:h=35:color=black@0.75:t=fill","drawtext=fontsize=30:fontcolor=white@.8:line_spacing=10:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Courier_Prime/CourierPrime-Regular.ttf:textfile=/YouTubeStream/CupolaCam/weatherdata/curtempformatted:y=h-line_h-5:x='if(gt(x\,-tw),w-mod(4*n\,w+tw)\,w)':reload=1" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -bf 2 -g 15 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -profile:a aac_low -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key"
```

The video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av6k8bf_2Zc

Comment: I think the solution somehow involves using sendcmd + reload but I still didn't figure out how to use sendcmd.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a workable solution but it isn't exactly how I wanted it to work. Ideally the text would scroll across the screen, update and then start a new pass. To avoid the text jumping around each time the weather would update I decided to convert the weather text into a fixed size image using ImageMagick. Then I overlay the image in ffmpeg and use the scroll filter to scroll it. Updated commands are as follows.

Create text file with weather data and convert to fixed size image (ImageMagick convert):

```
    echo "$humandatecc | Temp: $curtemp°F | Feels Like: $feelslike°F | Dew Point: $dewpntf°F | Humidity: ${curhumid}% | Wind: $suswind mph $suswinddir | Gust: $wndgust | Precip: $accprecip\" | Precip Rate: $rateprecip\"/hour" > /tmp/ccdata.tmp && convert -size 4075x30 xc:transparent -font "Courier-Prime-Regular" -pointsize 30 -fill "rgba(255,255,255,0.90)" -annotate +5+20 @/tmp/ccdata.tmp +repage /tmp/curtempformatted.png && mv /tmp/curtempformatted.png /YouTubeStream/CupolaCam/weatherdata/curtempformatted.png
```

Then I overlay the image in ffmpeg and use the scroll filter to scroll the image horizontally at the bottom of the video.

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -nostats -loglevel 8 \
        -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://192.168.x.x:7447/" \
        -f image2 -stream_loop -1 -re -i /YouTubeStream/CupolaCam/logo.png \
        -f image2 -stream_loop -1 -re -i /YouTubeStream/CupolaCam/weatherdata/curtempformatted.png \
        -f lavfi -i anullsrc \
        -filter_complex \
                 "[2]scroll=horizontal=0.0011[i2]; \
                 [0]drawbox=x=0:y=ih-35:w=iw:h=35:color=black@0.75:t=fill[v]; \
                 [v][1]overlay=20:925[vl]; \
                 [vl][i2]overlay=0:H-30" \
        -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -bf 2 -g 15 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -c:a aac -profile:a aac_low -b:a 128k -movflags faststart \
        -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key"
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this one too a while back and ending up by refreshing the ticker less frequent choosing a fixed width font and fixing the number of characters in the ticker by padding groups of text.

Not a real solution but the reload is visually a lot less disturbing.

[Drawing dynamic text on video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732317/drawing-dynamic-text-on-video-stream)